# LINQ double Join takes too long to execute

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query :

```
    var ftr_dist = db.DIST_VIEW.Where(x => x.CITY == "Los Angeles");
    var mst2 = db.TB_SERVICE.Where(x => x.ID == x.ID);
    var trf2 = db.TYPE.Where(x => x.ID == x.ID);

    var Data = (from ftr in ftr_dist
                      join mst in mst2 on ftr.CUSTOMER_ID equals mst.CUSTOMER_ID
                      join trf in trf2 on mst.TYPE_ID equals trf.ID
                      select new TypeObj { City = ftr.CITY, County = ftr.COUNTY, Type = trf.Type }
                      ).OrderBy(i => i.City).ThenBy(i => i.County).ToList();
```

ftr_dist has about 72000 rows. mst2 has 1100000 rows and trf2 has 340 rows. But it takes too long to get Data. How can I make this query faster? Thanks.

Comment: does it take significant shorter to get same results by raw sql?

Comment: Hook up a profiler and see what queries it's executing.

Comment: Do you have any indexes in these tables?

Comment: I would recommend trying this as TSQL in an SQL application, (eg SSMS for Sql Server)  and work on it there. Maybe some indexes or other performance modifications can be added at the DB side. Maybe you could create a view and just pull that back with a more direct statement than what LINQ can do for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are essentially performing 4 different queries. Linq does take longer to query than sql strings... try this staying with Linq. Combine all of the queries into one.

I am a little confused in your lambda queries the (x => x.ID == x.ID). You may need to add this to the below

```
var data = from ftr in db.DIST_VIEW
           join mst in db.TB_SERVICE on ftr.CUSTOMER_ID equals 
           mst.CUSTOMER_ID
           join trf in db.TYPE on trf.TYPE_ID equals ftr.ID
           where ftr.CITY == "Los Angeles"
           select new TypeObj 
           {
            City = ftr.City,
            Country = ftr.County,
            Type - trf.Type
           }.OrderBy(i => i.City).ThenBy(i => i.County).ToList();
```

Comment: I did what you said but it still takes too long.

Comment: How much time does the profiler have it taking to execute?

Comment: I have been waiting for 5 minutes and it's still working.

Comment: Trying to gather a little more info about your db... Could you possibly add some date ranges to narrow your search or is this historical data? Also do you normally run into query time issues when quering your db?